# Parse Cloud Code touch all records in database

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm wondering is it possible to touch/update all records in some class so they trigger before and after save hooks. I have a lot of records in database and it takes  time to update all manually via Parse control panel.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a cloud job which iterates through everything, but it would need to make an actual change to each object or it won't save (because the objects won't be dirty). You're also limited on runtime so you should sort by updated date and run the job repeatedly until nothing is left to do...

Comment: Do you have any example how I can do this .. maybe just update date created or something else ?

Comment: Maybe add a new column where you can set a Boolean, not sure on the best option really